# CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'corona.line'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console-application

i tried this in a c# console aplication and it worked but as soon as i shoved it in a unity program it diddent work plz help

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using RestSharp;

public class corona : MonoBehaviour
{

    RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/");
    RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

    string content = client.Execute(request).Content;
    string[] words = content.Split(' ');
    string line = words[832];
    string[] lineCut = line.Split('>');
    string Scases = LineLineCut[0] + LineLineCut[1];'''
```

Comment: **[Compiler Error CS0236](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236)**

Comment: Why not initializing all those fields in the constructor ?

Comment: `LineLineCut` was undeclared

Comment: Why do you tag unityscript but post C# code?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown would not have worked in a C# console application either, because you have field initializers referring to other fields (e.g. the `content` field initializer using `request`).

You probably want to put *all* of that code in a method instead:

```cs
public class Corona : MonoBehavior
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/");
        RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        string content = client.Execute(request).Content;
        string[] words = content.Split(' ');
        string line = words[832];
        string[] lineCut = line.Split('>');
        // Note: you haven't shown a declaration for LineLineCut.
        // You may have just meant lineCt
        string Scases = LineLineCut[0] + LineLineCut[1];
        // ...
    }
}
```

I strongly suspect that your working console application had code similar to this.

You may need to change the `RestSharp` code as well to a more Unity-centric HTTP stack - I don't know whether `RestSharp` is available in Unity. I'd also recommend trying to find a data source which isn't as brittle - accessing `words[832]` feels like it's just waiting to go wrong.

You'll then need to work out how to call the method at the right time, in some Unity-specific way, as well. But the first thing to get past is your field initializer compiler error.